# Alternate between form action with check box or radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two separate insert.php files... How would I alternate between them depending if a user has or has not ticked a checkbox or a radio button.

For example if my html is set up like so....

```
<form action="x.php" method="post">
```

and then the user ticks the check box, so the form would need to change to y.php

```
<form action="y.php" method="post">
```

How would this be accomplished?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use javascript function on radio button,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function OnSubmitForm()
{
  if(document.myform.operation[0].checked == true)
  {
    document.myform.action ="x.php";
  }
  else
  if(document.myform.operation[1].checked == true)
  {
    document.myform.action ="y.php";
  }
  return true;
}
</script>
<form name="myform" onsubmit="return OnSubmitForm();">

   <input type="radio" name="operation" value="1" checked>radio1
   <input type="radio" name="operation" value="2">radio2
   <p>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="save">
   </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Form is a tag and it has attribute. Action is a attribute of form tag, actually.

You can do it with javascript by change attribute of form tag when user choose checkbox, radiobutton (by catch event in javascript).

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it.

```
<form id="myForm" action="x.php" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chkbox" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#chkbox').click(function() {
            // `this` keyword is the native DOM object
            $('myForm').attr('action', this.checked? 'y.php' : 'x.php');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change the action of the form and are allowed to use javascript there is a quite simple

1. give the form a name, so that you can target it with javascript.
2. make a checkbox with an ID, then use an if statement to change the attribute 'action' of the form.

sample code below.

```
<form name="form1" action="x.php" method="post">
    <input id="changeAction" type="checkbox" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var checkBox = document.getElementById('changeAction');
    var form = document.form1;

    checkBox.onclick = function() {
        (checkBox.checked ? form.setAttribute('action', 'y.php') : form.setAttribute('action', 'x.php'))

        console.log(form);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Some inline javascript could do the trick quick

jQuery example:

```
<input type="radio" name="operation" value="1" checked onclick="$(this).parent().attr('action', 'x.php');">radio1
<input type="radio" name="operation" value="2" onclick="$(this).parent().attr('action', 'y.php');">radio2
```

Plain js

```
<input type="radio" name="operation" value="1" checked onclick="this.parentNode.action='x.php';">radio1
<input type="radio" name="operation" value="2" onclick="this.parentNode.action='y.php';">radio2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery and unobtrusive JavaScript...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $('#MyForm').submit(function(){
    var action = $(this).find('input[name=operation]:checked').val();
    $(this).attr('action', action);
  });
});
</script>

<form id="MyForm" method="post">

   <input type="radio" name="operation" value="x.php" checked>radio1
   <input type="radio" name="operation" value="y.php">radio2
   <p>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="save">
   </p>
</form>
```